# transversal surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have to prove that the surfaces $E=\{([0:x_{1}:x_{2}],[y_{1}:y_{2}])\in\mathbb{P}\mathbb{C}^{2}\times\mathbb{P}\mathbb{C}\}$ and $V=\{([x_{1}:0:x_{2}],[0:y_{2}])\in \mathbb{P}\mathbb{C}^{2} \times \mathbb{P}\mathbb{C}\}$ are transversal in $P=([0:0:1],[0:1])$, how can I do ?

Comment: you sure the tag is right? Its rather an algebraic geometry question. In differential topology, the question is trivial, the codimensions of the two surfaces add up to the codimension of the intersection set.

Comment: @ Troy Woo, this in no way guarantees transversality. Take any to tangent curves in the plane, e.g. $\{y=0\}$ and $\{y=x^2\}$.

Comment: I think that I have to show that the tangent spaces of the two surfaces meet only in P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the algebraic-geometric interpretation of transversality, the following is a solution in terms of differential topology, or differential geometry (both of which seem to me more appropriate tags to this question, by the way).

First note that at any $(p,q)\in\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ the tangent space is the direct sum $T_p\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2\oplus T_q\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$. We want to show that the sum of the tangent spaces to $E,V$ at the specified point is the whole tangent space of the ambient manifold, and it suffices to show it for each component separately. However, it is obvious that $TE$ covers the whole $T\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ component, thus we can focus on the $T\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ component, ignoring the $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ coordinate.

So let $E',V\subset\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ be given by $$E'=\{[0:x_1:x_2]\},\quad V=\{[x_1:0:x_2]\}, $$ and let $p=[0:0:1]\in\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$. It is easy to find specific tangent vectors $u_{E1},u_{E2}\in T_p E',u_{V1},u_{V2}\in T_p V'$ which are linearly independent, and this will end the proof, since the dimension of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ as a real manifold is $4$.

For specific examples of such vectors one can consider the paths $\alpha,\beta:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to E'$ given by $$\alpha(t)=[0:t:1],\quad\beta(t)=[0:it:1],$$ then take $u_{E1}=\dot{\alpha}(0),u_{E2}=\dot{\beta(0)}$, and repeat the process with similar paths on the other submanifold $V'$.